# Handling concurrency exceptions when passing the objects ids and timestamps using jQuery

Tags: entity-framework, concurrency, entity-framework-4, asp.net-mvc-5, model-binding

I have the following business scenario inside my Asp.net MVC 4 asset management system :-

> Scenario 1) A user selects multiple servers , then he selects a Rack Tag ,and click on
>   assign . so the selected servers will be assigned to the new Rack.
>
> Scenario 2) And i want to check for any concurrency exception , if for example the selected
>   servers have been modified by another user since they were retrieved .

so i have wrote the following jQuery which will send the object ids+timestamps to the action method:-

```
$('body').on("click", "#transferSelectedAssets", function () {
    var boxData = [];
     $("input[name='CheckBoxSelection']:checked").each(function () {
        boxData.push($(this).val());
    });

    var    URL = "@Url.Content("~/Server/TransferSelectedServers")";


     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: URL,
         data: { ids: boxData.join(","), rackTo: $("#rackIDTo").val()}
        ,
        success: function (data) {
       addserver(data);               })});
```

and inside the action method i have the following code:-

```
public ActionResult TransferSelectedServers(string ids, int? rackTo)
{

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            var serverIDs = ids.Split(',');
            int i = 0;
            foreach (var serverinfo in serverIDs)
            {
                var split = serverinfo.Split('~');

                var name = split[0];
                //System.Text.ASCIIEncoding encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();

                byte[] bytearray = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(split[1]);
                i++;
                var server = repository.FindServer_JTechnology(Int32.Parse(name));
                if (server == null)
                    return Json(new { IsSuccess = false, reload = true, description = " Some Servers might have been deleted, Transferre process has been cancelled .", rackid = rackFrom }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

                server.RackID = rackTo;
                server.timestamp = bytearray;
                string ADusername = User.Identity.Name.Substring(User.Identity.Name.IndexOf("\\") + 1);
                repository.InsertOrUpdateServer(server, ADusername, server.Technology.IT360ID.Value, server.IT360SiteID, new bool(), server.Technology);
            }

            repository.Save();


            return Json(new { IsSuccess = true, description = i + " Server/s Transferred Successfully To Rack " + }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
           catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException e)
        {
            return Json(new { IsSuccess = false, reload = true, description = "records has been modified by antoehr user" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);


        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return Json(new { IsSuccess = false, reload = true, description = " Server/s Can not Be Transferred to the Selected Rack "  }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);


        }
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = rackTo });

}
```

and the repository method looks as follow:-

```
public void InsertOrUpdateServer(TMSServer server, string username, long assetid, long? siteid = 0, bool isTDMHW = false, Technology t = null)
        {

                server.IT360SiteID = siteid.Value;
                tms.Entry(server).State = EntityState.Modified;
                var technology = tms.Technologies.Single(a => a.TechnologyID == server.TMSServerID);
                technology.IsManaged = t.IsManaged;
                tms.Entry(technology).State = EntityState.Modified;
                InsertOrUpdateTechnologyAudit(auditinfo);

            }
        }
```

but currently if two users selects the same servers and assign them to tow different racks , no concurrency exception will be raised ?
Can anyone advice ? baring in mind that if two users edit single object then one of them will get an concurrent exception message. so my timestamp column is defined correctly.

Thanks

Comment: I may be missing something but nowhere you send back the concurrency tokens from the client to the server. So first ensure you have them available on the client, then when calling your API send them back along with `ids` and `rackTo`, so that the server will be able to compare the timestamps of the client entities with the ones of the current entities you get from the repository.

Comment: yes the timestamps are available inside the client ,, but i can not understand what do u mean by "when calling your API ...". and in the worst case if the timestamp is not passed correctly then the update process should fail, since the timestamp will not be available inside the DB , but since the update process succeeded which means that the following statement inside my action method "server.timestamp = bytearray;" has no effect ?

Comment: So you should set the original value with it: `tms.Entry(server).Property(s => s.timestamp).OriginalValue = bytearray;`.

Comment: @Pragmateek  why i need to do so ? i mean the "server.timestamp = bytearray" should also assign the original value ..

Comment: @Pragmateek , i edit my code with  "tms.Entry(server).Property(s => s.timestamp).OriginalValue = bytearray;" , but i got the following exception Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.

Comment: The reason why you need to set the `OriginalValue` is that AFAIK when trying the `UPDATE` EF will emit a `WHERE` with the original value. So when you are in a **1-tier** scenario it keeps it in the context, but in a **n-tier** scenario like here your entities are disconnected so you need to explicitly tell EF what was the original value. As for your new exception check the SQL generated by EF, you can register with the `Log` hook.